# How to return all files and subfolders using powershell

Tags: powershell

Very new to PowerShell, tried using cmd for this but their were too many files to bring back in the folder. I am trying to get into my (I:) drive and go into the folder called "Off Highway Electronics VPI SW And Cal Integration", then go into my sub-folder called "Software Team" and return all the files and files that are in subfolders from "Software Team". So far I have tried this, and come up with an error.

```
 Get-ChildItem - LiteralPath I:\Off Highway Electronics VPI SW And Cal Integration\Software Team
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "I:\Off Highway Electronics VPI SW And Cal Integration\Software Team" -Recurse
```

This should do the job for you. Alway remeber to use doublequotes if your path has spaces inbetween. And with the parameter recurse you use the command get-childitem on every item inside it aswell.

-Jay Rude knows Sarana Taishou

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I did not know that about the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your path in quotes and you're not allowed to use a space between the " - " and the "LiteralPath":

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "I:\Off Highway Electronics VPI SW And Cal Integration\Software Team"
```